# How to read Mat elements one by one in C# OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

In C#'s OpenCV, I would like to check if two frames are equal.
But first, I would like to see the elements of the Mat file (which is matrix) just in case of other uses.

I used code below to read frame and write the array.

```
video.Read(frame);
Cv2.CvtColor(frame, frame_gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
vis = frame;
Console.WriteLine(vis);
```

But the result is different from Python.
the Console.WriteLine(vis) line gives me the following result.

```
Mat [ 640*480*CV_8UC3, IsContinuous=True, IsSubmatrix=False, Ptr=0x176f92587b0, Data=0x176fd347180 ]
```

How can I read the Mat datatype as array elements?

Comment: "in python" means numpy is printing its array. what specific OpenCV wrapper do you use for C#?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I use OpenCVsharp for C#

Comment: please clarify your question. are you asking how to touch individual array elements (I recommend against that; use opencv's whole-array manipulation functions) or do you need to "see" the array as text? I'd recommend just using imshow to look at your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose EmguCV as OpenCV C# wrapper, you can use GetData() and GetValue() methods. For example:

```
fundMat.GetData().GetValue(0, 0)
```